# Change the background image size with jquery for webkit

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-1.9

I want to change the background size with jquery. But it does not seem to work on safari and chrome.

```
$(".item").css({
    "background-size": 1046 * ratio,
    "-webkit-background-size": 1046 * ratio + " auto",
});
```

the original background size is `1046px X 200px`

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you remove `auto`?

Comment: I think your problem is somewhere else. It actually works, even without `-webkit-` prepend : http://jsfiddle.net/PZXvz/. Do you execute the js on dom ready ?

Comment: Yes I do. without that `-webkit-`, it wont' work. thanks.

Comment: Does adding the `px` solved the issue ? Otherwise, you should post your html, or try to make your own Fiddle.

Comment: Yea it seems to be working on certain elements. not all. strange!

Comment: Are you sure your `ratio` is not `undefined` in some cases ?

Comment: yes it has a value for sure. Apple is a pain just like IE...

Answer (score 5):

You are missing `px` after your x value. If you leave it, you will have a css property like
`-webkit-background-size: 524 auto` which is wrong. Here is the corrected code :

```
$("body").css({
    "background-size": 1046 * ratio,
    "-webkit-background-size": 1046 * ratio+'px auto',
});
```

See this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PZXvz/1/

What's strange is that the browser should fallback to the `background-size` property. Make sure you execute this on DOM ready :

```
$(document).ready(function(){/* your code */});
```

Comment: yes. i put it inside the dom ready. probably it is an Apple bug that causing it.